# question about flipping chain rule derivatives

Tags: calculus, derivatives, notation

If $$\frac{dy}{dx} = \left(\frac{dy}{du}\right)\left(\frac{du}{dx}\right),$$ will the inverse of $dy/dx$ flip the other derivatives? For instance, will $$\frac{dx}{dy} = \left(\frac{du}{dy}\right)\left(\frac{dx}{du}\right)?$$ Why/why not?

Comment: Why would you need to flip them, are you carrying out an implicit derivative of a function *of a function*?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are using the word *inverse* as the reciprocal of a term. Then, yes, inverting $\frac{dy}{dx}$ also inverts the other terms.

As you stated, $$\frac{dy}{dx} = \left(\frac{dy}{du}\right)\left(\frac{du}{dx}\right).$$

Then,
\begin{align*}
    \frac{dx}{dy} &= \left(\frac{du}{dy}\right)\left(\frac{dx}{du}\right) \\
    \frac{dx}{dy} &= \left(\frac{dx}{du}\right)\left(\frac{du}{dy}\right)
\end{align*}

where the last equation is when we apply the chain rule for $\frac{dx}{dy}$. Hence, we can somehow, say that inverting $\frac{dy}{dx}$ also inverts the terms when the
chain rule applied.

But remember that this is just an abuse of notation. About this, see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/21209/888233).